# Python. Найти повторы строк во множестве списков

Tags: python

Есть много списков. Несколько тысяч. Нужно найти совпадения каждого элемента каждого списка хотя бы с одним из остальных списков и с каким именно.

Есть ли для этого простая операция?
Или придётся городить огород с вложенными циклами и сравнивать каждый список с каждым из оставшихся?

Comment: dict: ключи - элементы всех списков, значения - списки списков, которые содержат данный ключ. Строится в один цикл.

Comment: Списки - текстовые файлы. То есть получается следующее... Ключ в словаре - это строка из файла, значение - список имён файлов, в которых находится данная строка???

Comment: Да, в вашем случае так. Это называется индекс.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Заведём словарь ключами в котором будут элементы списков. Под каждый ключ поместим список списков, которые этот ключ содержат:

```
import pprint

lists = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [5, 6, 7]
]

d = {}
for l in lists:
    for i in l:
        d.setdefault(i, []).append(l)

pprint.pprint(d)
```

> ```
> $ python list_instersections.py
> {1: [[1, 2, 3]],
>  2: [[1, 2, 3]],
>  3: [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]],
>  4: [[3, 4, 5]],
>  5: [[3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7]],
>  6: [[5, 6, 7]],
>  7: [[5, 6, 7]]}
> ```

Comment: Каждый список перебирается один раз. Это то, что нужно. Смог оптимизировать под свою задачу.